# RSA Cryptography shows wrong result for large prime numbers

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

I implemented a RSA Cryptography program, using python, and it works perfectly using prime numbers with aproximally 10 digits. But when I use numbers with 25 digits or more, for example, it does not work.

It worked with the following keys:

```
p = 2324731
q = 186647
e = 433899328297
n = 433904066957
```

It not worked with:

```
p = 3673864730662357928718503
q = 2127738717256957618781057
e = 7817024229395103552360986476332293342120062315901
n = 7817024229395103552360993847944520620136941797671
```

here's the code:

inverse (d key):

```
@classmethod
def __linearOperation(cls, a, b, mdc, i):

    t = -int(a / b)
    r = a % b

    mdc.append([1, a, t, b])

    if r == 1:
        return mdc

    inverseLine = cls.__linearOperation(b, r, mdc, i + 1)

    s = inverseLine[i][0]
    t = inverseLine[i][2]
    inverseLine[i - 1][0] *= t
    inverseLine[i - 1][2] *= t
    inverseLine[i - 1][2] += s

    inverseLine.remove(inverseLine[i])
    return inverseLine 

def __inverse(self, e, φ):
    
    inverseLine = self.__linearOperation(e, φ, [], 1)
    inverse = inverseLine[0][0]

    if inverse < 0:
        return inverse + φ
    if inverse > φ:
        return inverse % φ
    else:
        return inverse
```

Modular Exponentiation:

```
@staticmethod
def __QuickMod(base, exp, n):

    result = 1
    while exp > 0:
        if exp & 1:
            result = (result * base) % n
        
        base = (base ** 2) % n
        exp = exp >> 1

    return result
```

encrypt/decrypt:

```
def encryptChar(self, n: int, e: int, M: int) -> int:
    C = self.__QuickMod(M, e, n)  # C = M^e mod n
    return C

def decryptChar(self, p: int, q: int, e: int, C: int) -> int:
    d = self.__inverse(e, (p - 1) * (q - 1))
    M = self.__QuickMod(C, d, p * q)  # M = C^d mod n
    return M
```

By trying to encrypt the number `109` ("m" char in ascII), the encryptChar function returns `6825028446539883496812231478440519650519629664279`.
By trying to decrypt the number above the `decryptChar` function should returns the number `109` back. But that's not what happens.

In my conception, by using python we do not have number size restriction.
Is there something i'm not seeing? Thank you for your help.

Comment: `a / b` returns a `float`, which has limited precision. Use integer division `a // b`.

Comment: This is very hard to understand. `__linearOperation` sort of looks like a recursive version of the extended euclidean algorithm, but I can't be certain. Unless you are required to **not** use it, you really should acquaint yourself with the 3-argument version of the python builtin [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) function. It can replace your `__QuickMod` entirely and also computes inverses since python 3.8 when the exponent is -1.

Comment: Yes, __linearOperation is exactly what you've said. And I didn't know that I could use pow function for that. Well, I just use pow function and I got the same result. But i realized that the d*e mod p-1 * q-1 is not equal to 1 for large values of d*e. Then I think that maybe my euclidian algorithm have some problem. I'll try to solve it. Thanks for your help, it really helped.

Comment: Definitely the inverse algorithm has some problem. But I used pow() function with -1 as exponent and it worked perfectly. I'll re implement my inverse algorithm or just use pow() function. Any way, the problem is solved. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in my inverse algorithm. I'll try to re-implement it. But using pow() function with -1 as expoent works.